# Extra context is no passed to /accounts/login in django 3

Tags: django, django-3.2

I want to pass some configurable data to the login template and all other account template.

Currently, I am trying it like this:

```
# urls.py
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'), {'extra_context': {'home_title': settings.HOME_TITLE, 
                                                                          'domain': settings.HOSTNAME}}),
```

However, the data is not picked up by the template. And those variable remain empty strings. Is there a better way to do this?

For other pages I am passing the data in the views like this:

```
#views.py
def home(request):
    context = {'home_title': conf_settings.HOME_TITLE}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why doesn't this work?

There is no reason this would be added to the template context - that's just not how that particular argument works. (It's normally used to add extra arguments when calling a view, but those aren't automatically added to your template context - that's up to you inside the view!!).

#### What's a better way of doing this

Fortunately, Django does have something that is a perfect fit for this use-case: Context Processors. These insert additional variables into the context of every template. They're just functions that take a request and return a dict to be added to the context. e.g:

```
def my_context_processor(request):
    return {
        'home_title': settings.HOME_TITLE, 
        'domain': settings.HOSTNAME
    }
```

and then in your settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'path.to.my_context_processor'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

If you want to only add this for certain views, you could use the `request.match` object to inspect the namespace or app_name e.g:

```
# urls.py
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace="accounts")

def my_context_processor(request):
    if request.match.namespace === "accounts":
        return {
            'home_title': settings.HOME_TITLE, 
            'domain': settings.HOSTNAME
        }
    return {}
```

#### For more on Context processors

The Django docs are pretty good on this. Check out:

- [A bit about context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext)
- [Writing your own context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time writing this down. That is very insightful.